# why does this javascript timer reset sometimes

Tags: javascript

This code is a timer that keeps track of game racing times. For some reason it resets back to zero sometimes making the timer only get to 1-2 minutes. It's javascript. Is there some better way to do this? It's basically a stop watch. I need Hours minutes and seconds.

```
function go(){
    var m = 0;
    var s = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var h = 0;

    var timer_container = document.getElementById("output");
    timer_container.innerHTML = s + "." + m;

    timer();

    function timer() {
        if (m >= 9) {
            m = -1;
            s += 1;
        }
        if (s >= 60) {
            s = 0;
            min++;
        }
        if (min >= 60) {
            min = 0;
             h++;
        }
        if (s >= 0) {
            m += 1;
            var totals = h + ":" + min + ":" + s + "." + m;
            timer_container.innerHTML = totals;
            setTimeout(timer, 100);

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason this is tagged PHP or doesn't have any indentation?

Comment: should i maybe just make the same code in PHP instead of javascript

Comment: Increasing timeout to something more near a sec like 900 didn't helped? Since your smallest number is seconds, there's no actual need to run the function each 0.1sec, no?

Comment: Where do you call `go()`?

Comment: I call Go at the end of a countdown timer. this timer counts up.

Comment: Seams to work fine in isolation. The problem could be that you call the go function again some where by mistake and thus resetting the timer.

Comment: What happens when the timer resets? Does it start going again from 0 or does it stop altogether?

Comment: Also this timmer is going to be more inaccurate the longer it runs. Because setTimeout is terribly inaccurate it is seldom going to fire on 100 ms and thus are going to start to wander. you should instead use Date.now() or performance.now() to calculate a difference from the start time. Then the time is going to be right and the timeout only is for how ofthen you want to update the display.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL, I see hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds (well, deciseconds, but whatever).